# Having issues with outputting

Tags: java, arraylist

I am doing a program where I have a  addition quiz where they have to guess what number1 and number2 add up too, and I am spoused to let the user know if they already entered in a wrong guess more than once(like if they entered in the number 1 two times, on the second time I have to let them know they already submitted 1). I am using an array list but the issue is that  I am not outputting correctly as my book has it outputting.  would it be easier to do an array instead?
[This is the books output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkzFH.jpg)
[Here is my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3wSI.png)
Here's the code:

```
`import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RepeatAdditionQuiz {
     public static void main(String[] args){
        int number1 = (int)(Math.random()* 10);
        int number2 = (int)(Math.random()* 10);
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int answerOne = number1 + number2;
        System.out.print("What is" + number1 + " + "+ number2+"?");
        int answer = input.nextInt();
        list.add(answer);
         
        while (answerOne!= answer ){
            
          
             
            if (list.contains(answer) ){
            System.out.println("You have already submitted " + answer+ ".");
            System.out.print("Wrong Answer,Try again.What is" + number1 + " + "+ number2+"?");
                answer = input.nextInt();
                list.remove(answer);
                
            }
            
            else{
            System.out.print("Wrong Answer,Try again.What is" + number1 + " + "+ number2+"?");
                answer = input.nextInt();
                list.add(answer);
            }
            


            }
        
       System.out.println("You got it right!");
    }
} `
```

trying to match the output in the book

Comment: Use a do-while loop, not a while loop since you need to do the loop at least once, and need to get all input ***within*** the loop.

Comment: Also, in the future, please make your question title useful and informative. Your current title tells us very little of use, and does not summarize the actual problem. The [ask] and [tour] links can help you improve future questions.